# Why doesn't submitting a form via the submit method on the form element invoke $.submit handlers?

Tags: jquery, forms

See http://jsfiddle.net/8KNc7/5/ for a working example of what I am talking about (testing in Firefox 15 right now, haven't tried others).

I have a form with a `submit` input and a `button` input that both submit the form data to the server, but only the `submit` input causes the jQuery submit event to run. Why is this?

Form:

```
<form action='/echo/html/' method='post' id='Form' name='Form'>
    <input type='hidden' value='posted' id='html' name='html'>
    <input type='submit' id='submit1' value='submit type'>
    <input type='button' id='submit2' value='button type' onclick='submitForm();'>
</form>
```

Javascript (running at the end of the body tag):

```
var theForm = document.forms['Form'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.Form;
}
function submitForm() {
    theForm.submit();
}

$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        alert('ok');
    });
});
```

Point is, I am expecting both buttons to cause the alert but only one does. I know I can submit change the `submitForm` function to make it work properly but I am trying to figure out what the difference is in why one of these works and the other does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native form submit method bypasses the jQuery submit handler. You can use this to your advantage in several situations.

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // validation
    if (valid(this)) {
        this.submit(); // submit form, bypassing jQuery bound submit handler
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the jQuery event 'submit' only triggers when form is submitted by the submit type button.

> The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to
>   submit a form. It can only
>       be attached to  elements. Forms can be submitted either by clicking an explicit 
>       `<input type="submit">`, `<input type="image">`, or `<button type="submit">`, or by pressing Enter when
>       certain form elements have focus.

Taken from http://api.jquery.com/submit/

An approach would be to instead of your onClick event and JS function for the other button add an jQuery click() event handler:

```
$('#submit1').click(function(){
   alert('Ok');
   $('#Form').submit();
});
```

Comment: I am attaching to the submit event of the form element, aren't I. I am triggering it via javascript but I am doing so on the element that the event is attached to, right?

Comment: I would go for a complete jQuery solution instead of mixing with javascript only code. Why dont you add an jQuery click() handler instead for the other button? See my edit above.

Comment: I don't have access to all of the code running on the page or I would be using only jQuery.

Comment: Then go for the trigger() solution posted here by Blazemonger

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because `$('form').submit(...)` is jQuery, not pure JavaScript.

Whatever the reason, instead of using JavaScript's `form.submit()`, use jQuery's `.trigger()`:

```
function submitForm() { 
    $(theForm).trigger('submit');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8KNc7/6/